# Ubuntu 17.10 clean install, flickering screen

Tags: drivers, graphics, screen, 17.10

I've been looking for a solution to this issue but have been unable to find one, thus this question.

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10 and the screen is flickering quite a lot.  I've tried basic things like changing the resolution and refresh rate but that didn't help.

I ran lspci -v in terminal and got this on my graphics card:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 45) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at feb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Any Idea what could be wrong??

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu 17.10 uses [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) as a display server instead of [X.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server).

Wayland is pretty new and therefore has a lot of corner cases that need to be addressed (in fact, that's why the team behind Ubuntu decided to put Wayland by default, in order to find more bugs to be fixed later), but the good news is that it's possible to easily switch back to using X.org for the time being.

At the login screen, there is a little cog icon. Press it and you should have an option to use X.org instead:

[image: Screenshot showing the Xorg option]